# How i get Boolean From a Future[Settings]

Tags: scala, dictionary, filter

I have a Future [ProductSettings] which is returned from getProductSettingsMethod. Now I need the true or false from the clearedCanLoad field

```
   def getEmployerProductSettingsQuery(employer: Employer): DBIOAction[ProductSettings, NoStream, Effect.Read] = {
val productSettingsQ = productSettingsQuery.filter(_.employerId === employer.id).result
productSettingsQ.map(_.headOrServerException(s"Could not find ProductSettings for employer ${employer.id}"))
 }

   def getEmployerProductSettings(employer: Employer): Future[ProductSettings] =
db.run(getEmployerProductSettingsQuery(employer))
```

I tried .map, filter, flatMap etc. but none is working

```
def cleared (employer : Employer) :Boolean = {
val f : Future[ProductSettings] = 
 getEmployerProductSettings(employer)

  val iscleared: Boolean = f.filter { x =>
    x.clearedCanLoadSpenditCards match {
      case true =>
        true
      case false =>
        false
    }
  }
```

}

This is not working also not working is filter

```
val f : Future[ProductSettings] = getEmployerProductSettings(employer)

     val iscleared  = f . 
  .filter(_.clearedCanLoadSpenditCards.equals(true)).equals(true)

case class ProductSettings(id: Long,
                       employerId: Long,
                       enableCard: Boolean,
                       enableLt: Boolean,
                       enableLtRefundDays: Boolean,
                       enableLtConversion: Boolean,
                       enableLtOPayment: Boolean,
                       clearedCanLoad: Boolean,
                       clearedAt:Option[LocalDateTime]) {
```

equals true should return boolean but i get a Future[Boolean] back. How can i extract an Boolean

Comment: If possible you should return `Future[Boolean]` and modify the calling code to `map` the `Future` to access the `Boolean` inside it.

Comment: can you format your code? It's awful for reading

Answer (score 5):

The main purpose of the `Future` is to execute code asynchronously. Blocking the future to get the value from it defeats the purpose of it. But if you really need the `cleared` method to return `Boolean` you can block the future until its value is resolved.

You can achieve this by using `Await`:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val result: ProductSettings = scala.concurrent.Await.result(f, 1 second)
```

This will wait for the future be resolved. If a second passes and `f` is still not resolved this will throw a [TimeoutException](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/index.html#TimeoutException=java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException).

[scala.concurrent.Await#result](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Await$.html#result[T](awaitable:scala.concurrent.Awaitable[T],atMost:scala.concurrent.duration.Duration):T)

Comment: Rather than `IllegalArgumentException`, it should be [`TimeoutException`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/index.html#TimeoutException=java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException) if the specified `atMost` wait time has passed.

Comment: And `Await` (as `var`) should only be used when there is no other solution. Rather compose.

Comment: @leo Your're right. I updated my answer accordingly.